# URLConnection does not get the charset

Tags: java, http, content-type, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I'm using `URL.openConnection()` to download something from a server. The server says

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

But `connection.getContentEncoding()` returns `null`. What up?

Comment: this related thread might help anyone else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112259/obtaining-response-charset-of-response-to-get-or-post-request

Comment: Also there is a good reason connection.getContentEncoding() returns null: it returns the "Content-encoding" field of the http header, which **is not** supposed to give you a character set. It should be used for instance if the received data is compressed and gives you the way to use to transform the data so you can read it. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is documented behaviour as the `getContentEncoding()` method is specified to return the contents of the `Content-Encoding` HTTP header, which is not set in your example. You could use the `getContentType()` method and parse the resulting String on your own, or possibly go for a more [advanced](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html#getCharset%28%29) HTTP client library like the one from [Apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

Answer (score 28):

The value returned from `URLConnection.getContentEncoding()` returns the value from header `Content-Encoding`

Code from `URLConnection.getContentEncoding()`

```
/**
     * Returns the value of the <code>content-encoding</code> header field.
     *
     * @return  the content encoding of the resource that the URL references,
     *          or <code>null</code> if not known.
     * @see     java.net.URLConnection#getHeaderField(java.lang.String)
     */
    public String getContentEncoding() {
       return getHeaderField("content-encoding");
    }
```

Instead, rather do a `connection.getContentType()` to retrieve the Content-Type and retrieve the charset from the Content-Type. I've included a sample code on how to do this....

```
String contentType = connection.getContentType();
String[] values = contentType.split(";"); // values.length should be 2
String charset = "";

for (String value : values) {
    value = value.trim();

    if (value.toLowerCase().startsWith("charset=")) {
        charset = value.substring("charset=".length());
    }
}

if ("".equals(charset)) {
    charset = "UTF-8"; //Assumption
}
```

Comment: These methods are overridden to return sane values in HttpURLConnection which the OP is most likely talking about, see http://goo.gl/wt0P

Comment: the `substring()` argument should be `"charset=".length()+1`

Comment: @bigstones, no. The `length()` method returns the length of the string. The `substring()` method starts sub stringing values from position 0 and not 1, so `length()` is position `length() - 1`). Your solution can cause a `NullPointerException` if there is no values after the `=` sign.

Comment: ohh now I see what was wrong, I chained in the condition the `trim()` too,  so when taking the substring I was doing that on the untrimmed one. Thank you and sorry for doubting!

Answer (score 6):

Just as an addition to the answer from @Buhake Sindi. If you are using Guava, instead of the manual parsing you can do:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(httpConnection.getContentType());
Optional<Charset> typeCharset = mediaType.charset();
```