# How to read from a txt file in an http address from Java

Tags: java, file, http, readfile

I have an address like: "http://address.com/f1/f2/data.txt"

I'm implementing a Java program that needs to read from the text file, data.txt, preferably line by line, looking for a pattern.

I've searched, what I found  and tried was using BufferedReader and Jsoup(I know that using Jsoup doen't make that sense bacause the file is a text file not a html, but I tried it). None of them worked fine and in both I got this error:
(No such file or directory)

Here is my code:

```
public static String getData(String path, String pattern) {
    StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String str ="";
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
            if (str.equals(pattern))
                break;
        }
       str = in.readLine();
       in.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.toString());
       }
    return str;
```

}

Any clue how to read this file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259339/how-to-read-a-text-file-directly-from-internet-using-java

Answer (score 0):

```
    URL url = new URL("http://address.com/f1/f2/data.txt");
    URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
    InputStreamReader = inputStreamReader = 
        new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error: (No such file or directory) what do you think is the problem?

Comment: The problem is solved, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using below:

```
URL myurl = new URL(path);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                myurl.openStream()));
```

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) for your reference.