# obtaining response charset of response to get or post request

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httpclient

I am working to extract response charset in a java web app, where I am using Apache HTTP Client.

For example, one possible value obtained from "Content-Type" header is

```
    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Then my code will extract all text after the "=" sign...

So the charset as extracted will be

```
    UTF-8
```

I just wanted to know, is the above method for obtaining response charset correct? Or is there some scenario where the above code will not work? Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doesn't httpclient (or http core) already provide that functionality? Something like this:

```
HttpResponse response = ...
String charset = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: `@Deprecated` in recent apache httpClient versions. Uptodate answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34281952/1783163).

Answer (score 13):

The method provided by forty-two can work. But the method is deprecated, I find out that this [website](http://crunchify.com/java-how-to-get-entity-contenttype-in-httpclient/) has a good example of method to find the charset.

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
System.out.println("Charset  = " + charset.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, that approach will fail when

1. the charset value is quoted
2. when the quoted value uses escapes
3. when there are parameters other than "charset"