# Special characters escaping while reading html content via URL

Tags: java, aem

Below is the process followed.

I pass receiver name and html path via form submit. I append that parameter to the url and that paramter will dynamically added in html content.

I m able to see that special character passed appears correctly in my servlet.

but after i read the html content and display the content again, the special character is ecsaped. But the same character included in static content appears correctly when displayed. Below is the snippet used.

```
url = new URL(emailPagePath);

URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(),url.getQuery(), url.getRef());          

url = uri.toURL();

URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),ApplicationConstants.ISO_CHAR_SET);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

String inputLine;

StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

while ((inputLine =br.readLine()) != null) {

content.append(inputLine);

}
```

Comment: Any suggestion on this is very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Why all the URL/URI manipulation? Why don't you just use `URI` and do `.toURL()` at the last minute?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "special character is escaped" but that hints at an incorrect `Charset` value in the `InputStreamReader` constructor.

These previous answers provide more info about this:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)
- [URLConnection does not get the charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934251/urlconnection-does-not-get-the-charset)